# How do I make an HTTP request from Rust?

Tags: http, rust

How can I make an HTTP request from Rust? I can't seem to find anything in the core library.

I don't need to parse the output, just make a request and check the HTTP response code.

Bonus marks if someone can show me how to URL encode the query parameters on my URL!

Comment: TBD: https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/6167

Comment: @alex-dean, could you please change the marked answer to this question to correspond to reality now, in 2017. Thanks.

Comment: I’d like to delete my answer, but I can’t as it’s accepted. Please change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Update: This answer refers to fairly ancient history. For the current best practices, please look at [Isaac Aggrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14189088/493729) instead.

---

I've been working on [rust-http](http://github.com/chris-morgan/rust-http), which has become the *de facto* HTTP library for Rust (Servo uses it); it's far from complete and very poorly documented at present. Here's an example of making a request and doing something with the status code:

```
extern mod http;
use http::client::RequestWriter;
use http::method::Get;
use http::status;
use std::os;

fn main() {
    let request = RequestWriter::new(Get, FromStr::from_str(os::args()[1]).unwrap());
    let response = match request.read_response() {
        Ok(response) => response,
        Err(_request) => unreachable!(), // Uncaught condition will have failed first
    };
    if response.status == status::Ok {
        println!("Oh goodie, I got me a 200 OK response!");
    } else {
        println!("That URL ain't returning 200 OK, it returned {} instead", response.status);
    }
}
```

Run this code with a URL as the sole command-line argument and it'll check the status code! (HTTP only; no HTTPS.)

Compare with `src/examples/client/client.rs` for an example that does a little more.

rust-http is tracking the master branch of rust. <s>At present it'll work in the just-released Rust 0.8, but there are likely to be breaking changes soon.</s> *Actually, no version of rust-http works on Rust 0.8—there was a breaking change which can't be worked around in privacy rules just before the release, leaving something that rust-http depends on in extra::url inaccessible. This has since been fixed, but it leaves rust-http incompatible with Rust 0.8.*

---

As for the query string encoding matter, at present that should be done with [`extra::url::Query`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/extra/url/typedef.Query.html) (a typedef for `~[(~str, ~str)]`). Appropriate functions for conversions:

- [`extra::url::query_to_str`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/extra/url/fn.query_to_str.html)
- [`extra::url::query_from_str`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/extra/url/fn.query_from_str.html) (sorry, can't use this just at present as it's private. PR to make it public about to come. In the mean time, this link actually shouldn't work, it's only available because of https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/7476.)

Comment: how to compile it correctly? Right now I put it in rust-http/src/examples/client2/main.rs and run (taken from 'make examples' output)

    rustc -O -Z debug-info src/examples/client2/main.rs -o build/examples/client2 -L build/

Comment: @rofrol: rust-http currently generates a couple as a precompilation step, so you can't conveniently install it through rustpkg (which would otherwise be `rustpkg install github.com/chris-morgan/rust-http`) just yet. The important thing is that when you compile it it must be able to find libhttp-*.so; that's what the `-L build/` is for, because that file is in the `build` directory. So for your code it could be `-L /path/to/rust-http/build/`, or you could copy it into your build directory, or something like that. Don't worry, things should be quite a bit better by Rust 0.9 time.

Comment: Note that rust-http is now marked as obsolete. Its author recommends Hyper instead https://github.com/hyperium/hyper

Comment: heh, now it's replaced by hyper which is also poorly documented :>

Comment: There's Reqwest [sic] which is a simple wrapper around hyper. https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.3.0/reqwest/

Comment: I'm uncomfortable deleting this just because it's out of date...that doesn't seem to foreclose the possibility that someone might find it useful. If I could change the accepted answer, I would, but I can't. We'll need to wait for Alex to do that. It appears he's still an active user, so hopefully he'll see your comments on the question.

Comment: @CodyGray: archaeologists are the only people that could find it useful. The answer itself hasn’t been at all relevant for three years or so; the code involved won’t run, and rust-http itself would require some fairly invasive changes to be able to run, because this was from some time before Rust stabilised (1.0).

Answer (score 147):

The easiest way to make HTTP requests in Rust is with the [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) crate:

```rust
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let resp = reqwest::blocking::get("https://httpbin.org/ip")?.text()?;
    println!("{:#?}", resp);
    Ok(())
}
```

In `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["blocking"] }
```

### Async

Reqwest also supports making *asynchronous* HTTP requests using [Tokio](https://tokio.rs/):

```rust
use std::error::Error;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let resp = reqwest::get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
        .await?
        .text()
        .await?;
    println!("{:#?}", resp);
    Ok(())
}
```

In `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
reqwest = "0.11"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

### Hyper

Reqwest is an easy to use wrapper around [Hyper](https://hyper.rs/), which is a popular HTTP library for Rust. You can use it directly if you need more control over managing connections. A [Hyper](https://hyper.rs/)-based example is below and is largely inspired by [an example in its documentation](https://hyper.rs/guides/client/basic/):

```rust
use hyper::{body::HttpBody as _, Client, Uri};
use std::error::Error;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let client = Client::new();

    let res = client
        .get(Uri::from_static("http://httpbin.org/ip"))
        .await?;

    println!("status: {}", res.status());

    let buf = hyper::body::to_bytes(res).await?;

    println!("body: {:?}", buf);
}
```

In `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
hyper = { version = "0.14", features = ["full"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

### Original answer (Rust 0.6)

I believe what you're looking for is in the [standard library](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/index.html). now in [rust-http](http://github.com/chris-morgan/rust-http) and Chris Morgan's answer is the standard way in current Rust for the foreseeable future. I'm not sure how far I can take you (and hope I'm not taking you the wrong direction!), but you'll want something like:

```
// Rust 0.6 -- old code
extern mod std;

use std::net_ip;
use std::uv;

fn main() {
    let iotask = uv::global_loop::get();
    let result = net_ip::get_addr("www.duckduckgo.com", &iotask);

    io::println(fmt!("%?", result));
}
```

As for encoding, there are some examples in the unit tests in src/libstd/net_url.rs.

Comment: No, you need to configure the client to use a TLS implementation for https. See https://hyper.rs/guides/client/configuration/ for details.

Comment: doesn't work for hyper 13.  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60047494/8870055 below

Answer (score 22):

Using curl bindings. Stick this in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies.curl]
git = "https://github.com/carllerche/curl-rust"
```

...and this in the `src/main.rs`:

```
extern crate curl;

use curl::http;

fn main(){
  let resp = http::handle()
    .post("http://localhost:3000/login", "username=dude&password=sikrit")
    .exec().unwrap();

  println!("code={}; headers={}; body={}",
    resp.get_code(), resp.get_headers(), resp.get_body());    

}
```

Comment: A quick and low-friction approach - nice!

Comment: This answer proposes using C to do HTTP, but pure Rust solutions are more appropriate because they are simpler for a team to maintain, and also because Rust is safer than C.

Comment: @JeffAllen it may be more appropriate, but next to impossible to find. So I'd chose a sub-optimal that works to an "appropriate" that does not.

Comment: This would be much better than the other answer since it avoids dealing with "Futures", one of the most overly complicated, non-documented things I have ever seen. Too bad it doesn't work since there is no `curl::http` available (anymore) - only something called "easy" which is way to complicated on it's own and barely documented.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer Crates with low dependency count, so I would recommend these:

### [MinReq](//lib.rs/crates/minreq) (0 deps)

```
use minreq;

fn main() -> Result<(), minreq::Error> {
   let o = minreq::get("https://speedtest.lax.hivelocity.net").send()?;
   let s = o.as_str()?;
   print!("{}", s);
   Ok(())
}
```

### [HTTP_Req](//lib.rs/crates/http_req) (35 deps)

```
use {http_req::error, http_req::request, std::io, std::io::Write};

fn main() -> Result<(), error::Error> {
   let mut a = Vec::new();
   request::get("https://speedtest.lax.hivelocity.net", &mut a)?;
   io::stdout().write(&a)?;
   Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Just used minreq and can say it works really well. Be aware that it has 7 dependencies if you want HTTPS support.

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate on [Isaac Aggrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14189088/155423), here's an example of making a POST request with query parameters using the [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) library.

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "play_async"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
reqwest = "0.10.4"
tokio = { version = "0.2.21", features = ["macros"] }
```

Code

```
use reqwest::Client;

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;
type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

async fn post_greeting() -> Result<()> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let req = client
        // or use .post, etc.
        .get("https://webhook.site/1dff66fd-07ff-4cb5-9a77-681efe863747")
        .header("Accepts", "application/json")
        .query(&[("hello", "1"), ("world", "ABCD")]);

    let res = req.send().await?;
    println!("{}", res.status());

    let body = res.bytes().await?;

    let v = body.to_vec();
    let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(&v);
    println!("response: {} ", s);

    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    post_greeting().await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Go to https://webhook.site and create your webhook link and change the code to match. You'll see the request was received on server in realtime.

This example was originally based on [Bastian Gruber's example](https://github.com/gruberb/futures_playground/tree/6aecaf3c43df040431ab6bd7026dfc9dfa1013d5) and has been updated for modern Rust syntax and newer crate versions.

Comment: Do you have an example that uses a POST? HTTP forms allow for a GET and a POST, but this is using a GET.

Comment: @tom literally replace `.get` with `.post`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be enough. My request needs to be sent with Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". I tried adding a `header()` call with that and I'm getting back `HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.`

Answer (score 4):

Building upon [Patrik Stas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57770687/1042151), if you want to do an HTTP form URL-encoded POST, here is what you have to do. In this case, it's to get an OAuth `client_credentials` token.

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
reqwest = "0.10.4"
tokio = { version = "0.2.21", features = ["macros"] }
```

Code

```rust
use reqwest::{Client, Method};

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;
type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

async fn print_access_token() -> Result<()> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let host = "login.microsoftonline.com";
    let tenant = "TENANT";
    let client_id = "CLIENT_ID";
    let client_secret = "CLIENT_SECRET";
    let scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
    let grant_type = "client_credentials";

    let url_string = format!("https://{}/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token", host, tenant);
    let body = format!(
        "client_id={}&client_secret={}&scope={}&grant_type={}",
        client_id, client_secret, scope, grant_type,
    );
    let req = client.request(Method::POST, &url_string).body(body);

    let res = req.send().await?;
    println!("{}", res.status());

    let body = res.bytes().await?;

    let v = body.to_vec();
    let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(&v);
    println!("response: {} ", s);

    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    print_access_token().await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

This will print something like the following.

```
200 OK
response: {"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"ext_expires_in":3599,"access_token":"ACCESS_TOKEN"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [hyper](https://hyper.rs/) "0.13"

Also using [hyper-tls](https://crates.io/crates/hyper-tls) for HTTPS support.

File *Cargo.toml*

```
hyper = "0.13"
hyper-tls = "0.4.1"
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
```

#### Code

```
extern crate hyper;
use hyper::Client;
use hyper::body::HttpBody as _;
use tokio::io::{stdout, AsyncWriteExt as _};
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    // HTTP only
    // let client = Client::new();

    // http or https connections
    let client = Client::builder().build::<_, hyper::Body>(HttpsConnector::new());

    let mut resp = client.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact".parse()?).await?;

    println!("Response: {}", resp.status());

    while let Some(chunk) = resp.body_mut().data().await {
        stdout().write_all(&chunk?).await?;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Adapted from https://hyper.rs/guides/client/basic/

Answer (score 1):

Dropping a version here that uses the [`surf`](https://github.com/http-rs/surf) crate (dual to the [`tide`](https://github.com/http-rs/tide) crate):

```
let res = surf::get("https://httpbin.org/get").await?;
assert_eq!(res.status(), 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple http request with this crate: [wsd](https://crates.io/crates/wsd)

```rust
fn test() {
    wsd::http::get("https://docs.rs/", |data| {
        println!("status = {}, data = {}", data.status(), data.text());
    });
}
```