# Send raw data as an HTTPS request with Rust

Tags: http, ssl, rust, https

I would like to make an HTTPS request by sending raw data to it. In principle it would be something like this: [Make HTTP Request in Rust using std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346757/make-http-request-in-rust-using-std)

However, I would like to do it with SSL.

It is important to me that I don't have to "build" a request like you normally do with `reqwests` using different method. What I'm after is to simply get some data, like an example below, and send it via HTTPS to a server.

Example GET:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.server.com\r\n
```

Example POST:

```
POST /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.server.com\r\nContent-Length:14\r\n\r\nsomepostdata=1
```

EDIT:
Note that I don't want to do my own SSL implementation (obviously!). I'm after a simple API that would let me craft the request (as presented above) and send it to a web server using HTTPS (as if I was using telnet on HTTP). Hope that's clear (based on the doubts some expressed via their comments).

Comment: Your question strongly implied you wanted to write an HTTPS client using only `std`. If you're happy to use a library, there are several to choose from. TLS shims in between your socket code and the destination server, you basically "upgrade" your TCP socket to a TLS one, and then the rest is all regular reads and writes. For example, start with [`rusttls`](https://github.com/rustls/rustls).

Comment: @tadman yes! that exactly, thanks! :) Do you want to put that in the answer and I close this post?

Comment: It's just the "inspiration" part of the question. If you can get it working, worth adding a self-answer if you can explain it concisely with more technical detail than "use `rusttls`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @tadmad's comment, [rustls](https://github.com/rustls/rustls) is a good library that provides an encryption layer and at the same time allows for simple `reads` and `writes`.
Here's an excellent [example](https://github.com/rustls/rustls/blob/main/examples/src/bin/simpleclient.rs) showing how to implement exactly what I was after.