# How can I make a simple POST request in Rust?

Tags: http, oauth, rust

I'm new to Rust. I'm having a lot of trouble finding a simple example in Rust to make an HTTP POST request. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14189088/1042151) but it's using a GET not a POST.

In the end, all I want to do is POST like this:

```
POST /TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=MY_CLIENT&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&client_secret=MY_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

This is what I have as code.

```
[dependencies]
tokio-core = "0.1.17"
futures = "0.1"
reqwest = "0.10.4"
hyper = "0.13.5"
```

```rust
use hyper::{Client, Uri, Request, Body};
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

pub fn get_access_token() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();

    let client = Client::new();

    let host = "login.microsoftonline.com";
    let tenant = "TENANT";
    let client_id = "MY_CLIENT";
    let client_secret = "MY_SECRET";
    let scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
    let grant_type = "client_credentials";

    let url_string = format!("https://{}/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
                             host,
                             tenant,
    );
    let url: Uri = url_string.parse().unwrap();
    let body = format!("client_id={}&client_secret={}&scope={}&grant_type={}",
                       client_id,
                       client_secret,
                       scope,
                       grant_type
    );

    let req = Request::builder()
        .method("POST")
        .uri(url)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .body(Body::from(body))
        .expect("request builder");

    let request_result = core.run(client.request(req))
        .map(|res| {
            println!("Response: {}", res.status());
        })
        .map_err(|err| {
            println!("Error: {}", err);
        });
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `hyper::client::ResponseFuture: futures::future::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src/auth.rs:47:35
   |
47 |     let request_result = core.run(client.request(req))
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `futures::future::Future` is not implemented for `hyper::client::ResponseFuture`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I've found many different libraries to make HTTP requests (hyper, reqwest, http) but I am yet to find a working solution, and the Rust documentation isn't helping in that regard.

Also I tried using the [onedrive_api::Auth](https://docs.rs/onedrive-api/0.6.1/onedrive_api/struct.Auth.html) package but I didn't see a way to do a `client_credentials` grant type.

Comment: Read *all* the answers, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/57770687/155423

Comment: *Can't I just make a synchronous call and be done* — https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.4/reqwest/blocking/index.html

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you!

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437123/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster my request is asking how to do a POST not a GET. The link you provided (stackoverflow.com/a/57770687/155423) doesn't help me. That's doing Client.get() and I need a post. Thanks

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this.... makes me sad.